# Запуск adb команд в python

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, cmd, adb

Приветствую. Пытаюсь с помощью питон запустить некоторые комманды для андроида (install, uninstall, push). Сразу оговорюсь, что сторонние плагины/ модули не хотелось бы использовать. Можно обойтись subprocess? Между командами должна быть задержка.

Пробую подобное

```
process = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe',   stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)
process.stdin.write("adb shell uninstall com.q.q".encode("utf8"))
process.stdin.write("adb shell install C:\\...\\qwerty.apk".encode("utf8"))
```

но не работает, код просто завершается через секунду без каких либо ошибок и ожидаемого результата.

P.S. без encode возникает "ошибка a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Answer (score 1):

Нашел свою ошибку. 'shell' не нужен. И выглядеть это будет примерно так

```
subprocess.check_call(["adb", "uninstall", "com.q.q"])
subprocess.check_call(["adb", "install", "C:\\...\\qwerty.apk"])
```